# Replacement for setLoginListener in Wakanda 2

Tags: javascript, wakanda

In Wakanda 2 the method setLoginListener is removed (deprecated after v11, http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Wakanda%20Studio/0.Beta/setLoginListener.301-871936.en.html).
Unfortunately the documentation does not state which method(s) should be used instead. Or has this feature been completely abandoned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

directory.setLoginListener is replaced by directory.setLoginManager. you can find the documentation here [setLoginManager](https://wakanda.github.io/api-reference/interfaces/wakdirectory.html#setloginmanager)

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I kinda missed the new API documentation.